# No style ViewPagerIndicator in combination with SherlockActionBar

Tags: android, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm trying to implement the ViewPagerIndicator with SherlockActionBar. It works: I can slide the fragments, but the style doesn't work!

It looks like this:

[image: img]

related topic: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/issues/66

I know what's going wrong:
In the sample of VPI, the style of a page is set in AndroidManifest.xml by (for example)

```
<activity
     android:name=".SampleTabsDefault"
     android:theme="@style/Theme.PageIndicatorDefaults"> 
</activity>
```

But when I add that android:theme element to my own Manifest.xml I get the following exception:

```
03-16 11:06:24.400: E/AndroidRuntime(483): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
```

I've also tried to copy all the style-information to styles.xml, but that also doesn't work.

Can you tell me how to set a style to the VPI?
Thank you!

EDIT:
Now I've added

```
<activity
         android:name=".SampleTabsDefault"
         android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators"> 
</activity>
```

to my Manifest.xml

and the following style in styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.BataApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    </style>   

    <style name="StyledIndicators" parent="Theme.BataApp">
        <item name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TitlePageIndicator</item>
        <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator</item>
        <item name="vpiTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator.Text</item>
    </style>
```

Result: I don't get any Exception, see the style, but I now I can't see any fragments :(

The code of the activity can be found here: http://pastebin.com/hsNgxFDZ
Screenshot of current page with style:

[image: img]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In order to see the Fragments, you'll have to somehow extend an Android base-theme. In order to see the ViewPagerIndicator, you'll have to somehow include those style-definitions. The answer is to create your own theme that extends the ActionBarSherlock-theme (which extends the Android base-themes), and implements the ViewPagerIndicator-styles.

Example:

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">

    <!-- If you want to use the default ViewPagerIndicator-styles, use the following: -->
    <item name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TitlePageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator</item>
    <item name="vpiTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator.Text</item>

    <!-- If you want to implement your custom style of CirclePageIndicator, do it like so: -->
    <item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">@style/myCirclePageIndicator</item>


    <!-- Put whatever other styles you want to define in your custom theme -->
</style>

<style name="myCirclePageIndicator" parent="Widget.CirclePageIndicator">
    <item name="fillColor">@color/my_custom_circle_indicator_fill_color</item>
</style>
```

Then in your Manifest, set `android:theme="@style/myTheme"` to the `<application>` or to your `<activity>`s.

Note that you don't have to include all 4 "vpi..."-styles; you only have to include those that you use. E.g. if you're only using the CirclePageIndicator, you only have to include `<item name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle">...</item>` and can leave out the other 3 item declarations.

Comment: Well, that is exactly what i have described in my first post!
Theme.BataApp has as parent-style Theme.Sherlock... But still, I can't see my fragments showing up (I can see them without the extra styles)

Comment: Are your `Fragment`s getting called at all? Did you try setting `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` on your `ViewPager`? Could you post the XML of your layout?

Comment: Thank you so much! I accidentally removed android:layout_weight="1" from the xml :$

Comment: Great, I actually had the same problem a while ago when I was implementing this for an app! ;)

Comment: Haha! :) Is it possible to use the styles specified in SherlockActionBar? I really like the dark tabs, and I would like to use one 'centralised' style. This doesn't work:
 <style name="myTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/abs__tab_indicator_holo</item>
</style>

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'dark tabs'. To change the blue color, you'll have to create your own drawables and set `<item name="android:background">@drawable/my_tab_indicator</item>`. If you just want to change the background-color of the tabs, set a background to the ViewPagerIndicator itself.

Comment: There's no `vpiTabTextStyle` in the latest version, `android:textSize` and `android:textColor` are used instead as a part of the `TextAppearance.TabPageIndicator` style.

Comment: I added the style like this to my styles.xml, and was stuck for hours until I realized I had multiple styles.xml files. Needed to add to all.

Answer (score 5):

I accidentally removed android:layout_weight="1" when adding styles.

So for other who want to implement VPI with ABS:

layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        style="@style/StyledIndicators" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

styles.xml:

```
 <style name="Theme.BataApp" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
            etc.
        </style>   

        <style name="StyledIndicators" parent="Theme.BataApp">
            <item name="vpiTitlePageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TitlePageIndicator</item>
            <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator</item>
            <item name="vpiTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.TabPageIndicator.Text</item>
        </style>
```

Thank you @Reinier! :D

Comment: can you explain what does those "etc." mean? I'm having problem compiling this code - keeps telling "No resource found that maches the given name"