# Change viewpager style - no stripe but text highlighting

Tags: android, tabs, styles, android-viewpager

Is it possible to hide blue underlying stripe in viewpager and highlight tab titles instead? 
I need to make the selected tab title white and others gray.

Here's [an image](http://s4.uploads.im/aLgIS.png) explaining what i want to achieve.

I have no idea how to customize ViewPager layout. [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) is not suitable here as i understand.

My current layout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Corrected description.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `android:background="@null"` ?

Here is an example:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:animationCache="false">
    </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but It's not what i want. Corrected description, may be it wasn't clear

Comment: I'm not too sure about this, but check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24989468/3582991) , especially at the xml with the `TabPageIndicator`. Try changing the background of the `TabPageIndicator` to `android:background="@null"`?