# Using viewpagerindicator with ActionBarcompat

Tags: viewpagerindicator, android-actionbar-compat

I understand that `viewpagerindicator` is compatible with `ActionBarSherlock` and no mention is made of its compatibility with `ActionBarcompat` on their website. However, I was wondering if it is possible to use viewpagerindicator with ActionBarcompat `(android.v7.support)`.

With `ActionBarCompat`, you have to apply `Theme.AppCompat`, however with this theme,  the theme for Tabs using `TabPageIndicator` of `viewpagerindicator` does  NOT work.

Comment: I haven't tested all the indicator, but the circular is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewPagerIndicator` does not depend on `ActionBarSherlock`. It only depends on the android support library. 
When it comes to styling you need to override `vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle` in your stylesheet. The same you have to do with `ActionBarSherlock`.
I assume you are aware you need to include the `AppCompat` as a library module in your project to make the styles and other resources work. It's not enough to use the jar.

Please refer to the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737103/no-style-viewpagerindicator-in-combination-with-sherlockactionbar) thread for more details:

```
<style name="Theme.Mniamo.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/MniamoTabPageIndicatorLightDarkActionBar</item>
```

...

```
<style name="MniamoTabPageIndicatorLightDarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ng_tab_indicator</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">4dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MniamoTextAppearance.TabPageIndicator.Light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:lines">1</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
</style>
```

Of course you need to replace ABS styles with respecitive styles from the AppCompat lib.